# How do I query for data that falls between two dates?

Tags: php, sql, mysql

I have an html form to select two dates from dropdown. Now I need to retrieve all records from a MySQL database which lie between those dates. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Please post code for your form and the structure for the table you wish to query...

Comment: Not PHP5 specific, please tag correctly. http://php.net/ChangeLog-5.php I've also added MySQL since it deals with that.

Answer (score 2):

Provided that $startDate and $endDate are in YYYY-MM-DD format (and $startDate is date before $endDate), you would probably need a query like :

```
$sql = "select field1, field2, ... from yourtable where yourdatefield between $startDate and $endDate";
```